# AWS S3 static site w/ cloudfront - without making the bucket public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm trying to host a static site from S3. I had it previously set up where Route 53 was configured to redirect traffic to CloudFront, which has my public S3 bucket cached. When I make the bucket private, my whole site goes down. I had set ACLs to allow traffic from CloudFront but even with that going to my website will provide a 403 Forbidden Error.

What am I missing here? Is there a good tutorial to follow for my use case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think this would help you, https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/ (the Using a website endpoint as the origin, with access restricted by a Referer header the part) to summarise it you need to give a specific header from your cloudfront to your s3 and change the bucket policy to accept get requests only that have only this header.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to solve this is via an [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html), which allows CloudFront to access a private S3 bucket.